# How to pass a request to sagemaker using postman

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-sagemaker

I've trained a model on sagemaker and have created the endpoint. I'm trying to invoke the endpoint using postman. But when training the model and even after that, I have not specified any header for the training data. I'm at a loss as to how to create payload while sending a post request to sagemaker

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once the endpoint is created, you can invoke it as any other restful service, with credentials and payload.

I am guessing, there could be two places where might be stuck. 
One could be, sending an actual PostMan Request with all the headers and everything. 
Newer version of Postman has AWS Signature as one of the Authorization types. You can use that to invoke the service. There are no other spacial headers required. Note that there is a bug in Postman still open ([issue-1663](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1663)) that only affects if you are a AWS federated account. Individual accounts should not be affected by this issue.

Or, you could be stuck at the actual payload. When you invoke the SageMaker endpoint, the payload is passed as is to the model. If you want to preprocess the input before feeding it to the model, you'd have to implement an input_fn method and specify that when instantiating the model.

You might also be able to invoke SageMaker endpoint using AWS SDK boto3 as follows

```
import boto3
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

payload = getImageData()


result  = runtime.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName='my_endpoint_name',
    Body=payload,
    ContentType='image/jpeg'
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an example for calling the sagemaker endpoint created in the quickstart guide. You can call it using `text/csv` or `application/json` formats:

In Postman:
The url you want is POST https://runtime.sagemaker.{{region}}.amazonaws.com/endpoints/{{aws_model_name}}/invocations

In the Authorization tab, choose type `AWS Signature` and put in the values for your `AccessKey` and `SecretKey` (recommend you use variables for these), and `sagemaker` for Service Name.

Under Headers add:

`Content-Type` : `text/csv`

`Accept`: `application/json`

In Body: paste in your body, separated by commas (if yr following the quickstart guide, in the notebook you can simply run `print(valid_set[0][60:61])` to get an example vector. You'll need to convert that value set into comma separated values

Clicking `Send` and you should be good to go!

For sending JSON data, change the `Content-Type` to `application/json` and you'll want the structure to look like this:

```
{
    "instances":[
        {
            "configuration": {},
            "features": [...]
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried the above appraoch to test sagemaker endpoint from postman, but received the following error:
{
    "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n 
...
}

I am using sagemaker studio to train my model and deploy using sagemaker sdk. In Postman I used the access key of the role that I created for the sagemaker studio.