# How to invoke a sagemaker endpoint from Grafana

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying with AWS sagemaker and created endpoint successfully. I want to visualize the data on Grafana now. Can anyone suggest an approach to this?

Answer (score -1):

While I am not familiar with Grafana and exactly what you would like to visualize, the only way to Invoke the Endpoint is using the [InvokeEndpoint API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html).

This API can be hit using any of [these SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html#API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint_SeeAlso). You can also make a direct post request to the runtime API. Kindly see this question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675637/how-to-pass-a-request-to-sagemaker-using-postman).

Having said all this, SageMaker Endpoints are designed for realtime inference. That is, a request is sent to the Endpoint and a response is returned.

If you would like to visualize a large amount of inference data. You could look at using a [SageMaker Batch Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html) Job. The output of the Job will be files(s) in S3 that you could ingest.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone looking at this in 2023+. I'm pretty sure OP just wants/needs to visualize the performance data coming in from the endpoint. Latency, Disk Utilization, 4xx errors and such.

As far as I can tell this **should** be supported in (Amazon Managed) grafana via cloudwatch, but it **currently does not work** the way it should.
All of my queries to AWS/Sagemaker either return nothing or tell me the endpoint could not be found. It is possible that this functionality still needs to be fully added.

It's almost impossible to tell why these are failing and it seems there is no reference material of anyone doing it in this way yet as a search for "grafana" + "sagemaker" turns up dry.